# List of assemblies in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, list, dll, sqlclr

i have many assemblies installed on my sql server 2008, now i want to get the list of assemblies, how to get the list using select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select * from sys.assembly_modules
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180052.aspx